# Analyse gzip request

Tags: request, gzip, mountebank

I am exploring mountebank and have a case where I need to analyse the gziped json request in order to create a predicate that returns the appropriate response. Can I unzip a json request and analyse the json with mountebank?

Answer (score 0):

It does sound possible using [Injection](http://www.mbtest.org/docs/api/injection) - this way, you should be able to require [zlib](https://nodejs.org/api/zlib.html) in your JavaScript function, use it to unzip the payload, parse the result to JSON and then return a response as you see fit.

Depending on what you want to return though, you may need to use a combination of Predicate Injection (where a simple true/false determines whether or not the stub responds) and Response Injection (where you can tailor the response depending on the content of the payload).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late reply - but I thought I would add an answer.

Please see https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mountebank-discuss/lvJq9PdIRlo for an update. There is now an open ticket to add support for this.